# Wagtail FormBuilder - how to use form data in the landing template?

Tags: python, formbuilder, wagtail

I used Wagtail's contributed Form builder module to create a simple Contacts form in Wagtail Admin. The form has the dynamically added fields *Name*, *Email*, *Subject* and *Message*; the model `ContactPage` inherits from `AbstractForm`.

**The problem:**

I would like to use the entered name in the *Name* field to personalize the response message to the user who used the contact form. Wagtail's Read The Docs page on Form builder only states that `form` is part of the context for the *form_page.html* template, while the *form_page_landing.html* template is a standard template. Is it possible to access the form-submitted values through the context of the landing template out of the box somehow? If not, could anyone give an example how/what page function to override, in order to add the information I need to the context? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wagtail serves its forms pages through `AbstractForm` (https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/contrib/forms/models.py#L296) and specifically its `serve` method. This method checks to see if the HTTP method is 'POST' so it either processes the form and returns the landing page or it renders the actual form. You can override this method to your custom form class so it updates the context of the landing page, something like this:

```
   def serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = self.get_form(request.POST, page=self, user=request.user)

            if form.is_valid():
                self.process_form_submission(form)
                
                # Update the original landing page context with other data
                landing_page_context = self.get_context(request)
                landing_page_context['name'] = form.cleaned_data['name']

                return render(
                    request,
                    self.get_landing_page_template(request),
                    landing_page_context
                )
        else:
            form = self.get_form(page=self, user=request.user)

        context = self.get_context(request)
        context['form'] = form
        return render(
            request,
            self.get_template(request),
            context
        )
```

Now the landing page context will have a `name` context variable containing the value of the name form field!